# He's not/He won't

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

A - OK, but maybe he wants it back if he comes back sometime.

B - He's not./He won't.

What would be correct and natural here?

Comment: His coming back is conditional, so maybe *He wouldn't*? *He won't* is ambiguous - compare *He won't [come back]* and *He won't [want it back]*

Answer (score 2):

"**maybe he wants it back if he comes back**" is poor English.

Poor **style**:

If there's any alternative to the repeated "back", a native speaker would prefer it: "...wants it back if he comes home" or "... needs it if he comes back."

Poor **grammar**:

To speak about the future it should be:

"...maybe he **will want** it back if he comes home sometime."

But if he *does* sometimes come back/home it should be:

"...maybe he **wants** it back when he comes home sometime**s**."

The answer to the first might be "**He won't**"
The answer to the second might be "**He doesn't**".
But as Andrew said, the replies are ambiguous. Do they mean *he doesn't/won't need it* OR *he doesn't/won't come back*?